# How to use jest to mock a function just for some specified arguments, but uses its original logic for any other arguments?

Tags: unit-testing, jestjs, mocking

Say I have a function:

```
function complexCompute(num: number): string {
   switch(num) {
      case 1: return '...something...';
      case 2: return '...something...';
      case 3: return '...something...';
      // more cases
}
```

It is used many times in the code I want to test, but I want to mock it like this:

- when I pass the argument `num` is `1`, `complexCompute` returns my mocked string `my-mock-string1`
- when I pass any other argument, it uses its original logic

I can't find a way to do it, since if I mocked the module:

```
jest.mock('./complexCompute')
```

The mocked `complexCompute` doesn't have original logic. I have to define the mock value for argument `1`, and also rewrite the whole logic for other arguments.

Is there any way to do it?

Comment: Don't? Why do you only want to isolate what you're testing from the implementation of complexCompute when it's called with 1? Why not decouple them entirely?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To access the actual implementation for a mocked module you can use [jest.requireActual(moduleName)](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/jest-object#jestrequireactualmodulename).

Here are two examples:

`Mocking the entire module`

```
jest.mock('./complexCompute', () => {
  const actual = jest.requireActual('./complexCompute').default;

  return {
    default: (arg: number): string => arg === 1 ? 'my-mock-string1' : actual(arg)
  }
})
```

`Using auto-mock with` [.mockImplementation](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/mock-function-api#mockfnmockimplementationfn)

```
import complexCompute from './complexCompute';

jest.mock('./complexCompute')

complexCompute.mockImplementation((arg) => {
  return arg === 1
    ? 'my-mock-string1'
    : jest.requireActual('./complexCompute').default(arg)
});
```

[working TypeScript example](https://repl.it/@StefanTeneff/ts-jest-mock-function-only-for-specific-args#test2.spec.ts)

Comment: Thanks! Seems like `jest.requireActual` is the only way. I managed to use 'jest-when' to make it a little bit more flex: `beforeEach(() => 
 { when(complexCompute).mockImplementation(jest.requireActual('./complexCompute').default); })`, then in test case, I can use `when(complexCompute).calledWith(1).mockedReturnValue(mockedValue)` to mock only the arguments I concerned